# SAMBA shares are not working unless I enter an iptables command at every boot

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-networking

I have recently enabled `ufw` in Linux and found that in order for my Samba shares to mount correctly, I need to enter this command

```
sudo iptables -t raw -A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j CT --helper netbios-ns
```

However, it is somehow forgotten at the next reboot and I have to enter it every time.

Is there a way to make this iptables command stick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iptables rules are not persistent, and UFW cannot read and save rules added directly using iptables. Instead, you should be using the UFW to add the rules, e.g.

```
sudo ufw allow 134/udp
```

Or if you have Samba application rules installed:

```
sudo ufw allow samba
```

This will allow all ports used by Samba, as the application rule is something like:

```
[Samba] 
title=LanManager-like file and printer server for Unix 
description=The Samba software suite is a collection ...
ports=137,138/udp|139,445/tcp
```

You could also [make iptables rules persistent](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-save-iptables-firewall-rules-permanently-on-linux/) by installing `iptables-persistence` and using `iptables-save`, but it is not recommended to mix this with UFW.

Comment: I have already added my Samba firewall rules for those ports, that's not the issue. The actual Samba shares won't mount in Linux Mint unless I have that iptable rule in place.